# Is it possible to run npm install without Python path present in Environmental variable

Tags: node.js, windows, cmd, npm, npm-install

I am trying to install @angular-cli through npm.

I am getting the below error.

```
gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
```

I guess, python is not present in the path. But i dont have administrator account, to make changes in environmental variable.

Is there any way to run **npm install -g @angular/cli** by mentioning python path while running **npm install**.

Answer (score 2):

You can set previously npm's 'python' config key to the appropriate value:

```
$ npm config set python /path/to/executable/python2.7
```